# Applying Discrete wavelet transformation (DWT) on a given data set using Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, graph, dwt

I have a stock market data set with the following two fields:

- date
- closing_price

I would like to apply DWT on this data set and plot a graph using Matlab. Can some one please guide me how to do it..

Thank you

**EDIT**

here is an example set of data

Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume

24-Oct-03,29.12,29.2,28.93,29.16,3069600

23-Oct-03,29.5,29.69,29.34,29.55,3414200

22-Oct-03,29.95,29.95,29.49,29.65,6659700

It is CSV.

I need to plot a DWT graph where x axis is date and y axis is any one or all of the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Computing DWT

This is actually straightforward. Use [`dwt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/wavelet/ref/dwt.html) to obtain the approximation and detail coefficients. For instance, a DWT using a daubechies 4-tap wavelet would be:

```
[cA, cD] = dwt(X, 'db4')
```

where `X` is your data.

If each sample in `X` has several fields, and you want to apply the DWT just on a certain field, say `X.closing_price`, add square brackets:

```
[cA, cD] = dwt([X.closing_price], 'db4')
```

Note that this solution assumes that the data samples are taken at **constant time intervals**.
To plot the data, you need to prepare another vector, which corresponds to the day number:

```
t = 1:2:length(X);
```

The x-axis values skips every other day because the approximation and detail coefficients vectors each have half of the samples of `X`.

### Demo code

The following code generates random data and puts it into an array of structs, each element having two fields: `date` and `closing_price`:

```
%# Generate some random data
C = cell(31, 2);
C(:, 1) = arrayfun(@(z)[num2str(z), '-Oct-03'], 1:length(C), 'Un', 0);
C(:, 2) = num2cell(100 * randn(1, length(C)));
X = cell2struct(C, {'date', 'closing_price'}, 2);
```

Now, to business:

```
%# Apply DWT
[cA, cD] = dwt([X.closing_price], 'db4');

%# Prepare x-axis values
t = 1:2:length(X);

%# Plot result with respect to date
figure
subplot(2, 1, 1), plot(t, cA)
title('Approximation coefficients'), xlabel('day'), ylabel('C_A')
subplot(2, 1, 2), plot(t, cD)
title('Detail coefficients'), xlabel('day'), ylabel('C_D')
```

This is what you should get:

[image: Expected result]

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am getting an error while plotting the graph.it says "Error using plot. Vectors must be the same lengths." also is it possible to have the date value itself in the x axis (I meant not changing them into 1 2 3 4 etc)...

Comment: size(cA)=size(cD)=19 and size(t)=31 .... after applying [cA, cD] = dwt([X.closing_price], 'db4'); cA and cD counts will become lesser than the count of input data... hence I am getting the error "Vectors must be the same lengths"...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. So, will I not be able to plot for each day?

Comment: In short, no. But I mislead you a little, I set the x-axis values to be from 1 to 19 to avoid the error. In reality, the x-axis values should be `1:2:length(X)`, skipping every other day. I still find it weird that `length(X)` is 31, but `cA` and `cD` are 19 samples each. They are supposed to have half the samples of `X`, each. Please note that I corrected the solution, but you should look into your data and verify that.

Comment: I wanted to know one more thing.. Is it possible to use whos and get the amount of memory(RAM) used by a function while finding DWT

Comment: Well, you can put `whos('cA', 'cD')` after the `dwt` command to see how much memory they take. Is that what you mean?